# After optimizing project with r.js, and building concatinated-minified main.js, browser still loads js files from their respective dist/folder

Tags: angularjs, optimization, requirejs, r.js, angular-amd

An Angular project I'm involved in uses RequireJS.
Now I'm trying to optimize the project using r.js.

The following is my Angular Project Structure

```
 .
 |_ js            // all the libaries are in here
 |_ css           // all style sheets
 |_ ngApp         // app.js and some config files
 |_ ngControllers 
 |_ ngServices
 |_ ngFilters
 |_ ngTemplates
 |_ ngViews
 |_ ng_modules
 |
 |_ build.js
 |_ index.html
 |_ main.js    // RequireJS paths and shims
 |_ r.js
```

Following is my r.js build script

```
({
   dir: 'dist',// the output directory
   optimizeCss: 'standard',
   removeCombined: true,
   mainConfigFile: 'main.js',
   name : 'main',
   fileExclusionRegExp: /^((r|build|gulpfile)\.js|(node_modules))$/
})
```

Script tag used to add RequireJS is below.

```
<script data-main="main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

My require.js config in main.js

```
'use strict';
require.config({
    waitSeconds: 0,
  paths: {
    jquery: 'js/jquery-1.11.3.min',
    angular: 'js/angular.min',
    angularAnimate: 'js/angular-animate.min',
    app: 'ngApp/app',

    /*Directives - Start*/
    masterHeaderDirective: 'ngDirectives/master-header-directive',
    .
    .
    .
    /*Directives - End*/

    /*Services - Start*/
    interceptor: 'ngServices/Common/app-service-interceptor',
    .
    .
    .
    /*Services - Start*/

    /*register Filters - Start*/
    currencySymbolFilter: 'ngFilters/currenySymbolFilter',
    /*register Filters - End*/

    /*Controllers - Start*/
    mainController: 'ngControllers/mainController.js',
    .
    .
    .
    /*Controllers - Ends*/

    /*textAngular*/
    textAngular: 'js/textAngular/textAngular.min',
    textAngularRangy: 'js/textAngular/textAngular-rangy.min',
    textAngularSanitize: 'js/textAngular/textAngular-sanitize.min',

    modernizr: 'js/modernizr.custom',
    detectizr: 'js/detectizr',

    /*i18n custom*/
    i18nCustom : 'ngDirectives/i18n-custom-directive',
    i18nCustomService : 'ngServices/Common/i18n-helper-service',
    i18nCustomController : 'ngControllers/Common/i18n-helper-controller',
    /*i18n custom ends*/

  },
  shim: {
    'angular': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'angular' },
    'angularAnimate': { deps: ['angular'] },
    'angularRoute': { deps: ['angular'] },
    'dirPagination': { deps: ['angular'] },
    .
    .
    .
  },
   deps: ['app']
});
```

At the end of build, I get `dist` folder with all my .js and .css files minified in their respective folders. Also, `main.js` inside dist folder contains the minified concatenation of all files mentioned in main.js.

But when I open my dist folder in browser, instead of using controllers, services etc from the minified-concatenated `main.js`, they are being loaded from their respective `dist/folder`.

If I remove a folder, for eg. `dist/ngController`, the app breaks, which means that the presence of files in `dist/ngController` inside dist/main.js is not respected. Could some one explain this behaviour.

Comment: Please add to your question your RequireJS configuration, and the `script` elements that load the RequireJS configuration and start your app in the same order they appear in the HTML.

Comment: @Louis, I've edited the question with script tag and require config. All other scripts are loaded through require only

Comment: It there any `require` call outside your `main.js` *after* the build?

Comment: No, none at all. You see, I have mainController inside dist/ngControllers folder as well as in dist/main.js. If I delete the one in dist/ngControllers, the app breaks.

Comment: Well, then I'm just not seeing it. I thought maybe you ran into an issue similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005682/requirejs-optimization-into-multiple-modules). The OP there uses multiple modules, which makes the problem more likely. But if you do have a single module and you to have a `require(['X'])` call somewhere *outside* the bundle and `X` is a module *inside* the bundle, then you need to use the `bundles` configuration to make it work reliably. But you say you don't have `require` calls outside the built `main.js`, so... this is not it.